In triangle with sides $(a,b,c)$ is the minimum value of $\frac{aR+br}{A}$ related to the tetrahedral bond angle?
Definition: Let $\theta_t = \arccos(−1⁄3) \approx 1.910633$ be tetrahedral bond angle constant. In a tetrahedral molecular geometry, a central atom is located at the center with four substituents that are located at the corners of a tetrahedron and the electrons will try to locate themselves as far away from each other as possible. This results in an arrangement of electrons in tetrahedral molecules at bond angle of $\arccos(−1⁄3) \approx 1.910633 \approx 109.4712206°$.
Let $(a,b,c)$ be the sides of a triangle whose area is $A$, circulradius is $R$ and inradius is $r$. Experimental evidence show that
$$
\min\left(\frac{aR+br}{A}\right) \approx 1 + \frac{\theta_t}{\sqrt{5}}.
$$
with an error less than $9.66 \times 10^{-7}$. Is this is coincidence or is there some underlying relation between the LHS and the tetrahedral angle constant.

this expression is basically this: $\frac{1}{\sin(\beta)\sin(\gamma)} + \frac{2\sin (\beta)}{\sin(\alpha) + \sin(\beta) + \sin(\gamma)}$ for $0 < \beta, \gamma, \beta + \gamma < \pi$

Probably  a coincidence but a nice one !
